# Interactive Video in android device

Tags: android, video, format, interactive

Does android supports interactive video?

If yes, can anyone suggest the format it supports and android version.

I have a requirement where i need to show the list of videos and it will play on selecting. No the video will be a interactive video so that user can intervene and based on the user's request action will be performed in video.

Comment: can you show the example of interactive video?

Answer (score 0):

> Does android supports interactive video?

No, if by "interactive video" you mean "user can intervene and based on the user's request action will be performed in video".

Answer (score 0):

no problem, it works great, like we did it here:

http://culture.austria.info/

html5 javascript video support is quite powerfull, but still tricky and needs quite much experience.